# Create Symfony Form Without Form Component

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I create the form element using custom html, not using the form components. Can you please tell how to get the value and select the dropdown value on edit mode. I used like following but occur error

**Controller** UsersController.php

```
public function edit($id) {
 if (!$user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Users::class)->find($id)) {
  $this->addFlash('danger', 'User not found!');
   return $this->redirectToRoute('users');
 }
}
return $this->render('users/form.html.twig', array(
 'page_title' => 'Edit User',
 'groups' => $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Groups::class)->getGroups(),
 'data' => $user
));
```

**Template** form.html.twig

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
     <label class="input-label req">Group</label>
     <select name="group" id="group" class="form-control" required>
      <option value=""></option>      
      {% if groups|length > 0 %}
       {% for v in groups %}
        <option value="{{ v.id }}"{{ data.getGroup == v.id ? ' selected' : '' }}>{{ v.group_name }}</option>
       {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
     <label class="input-label req">First Name</label>
     <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control" value="{{ data.getFirstName }}" required />
    </div>
   </div>
```

**input type (text)** value is coming, but on **select dropdown**, it shows following error :-

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Object of class Proxies__CG__\App\Entity\Groups could not be converted to int").

how to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Use `{% if groups is defined %}` instead of `length > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
data.getGroup.id
```

Instead of

```
data.getGroup
```